# Farkas lemma and duality

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

In his blog, Terence Tao proves the following this version of [Farkas lemma](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/11/30/the-hahn-banach-theorem-mengers-theorem-and-hellys-theorem/).

**Propsition.**   For $i=1,\dots,m$ let $P_i:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ be affine linear functions.
Then TFAE

1. there is an $x$ such that $P_i(x)\ge 0$ for all $i=1,\dots,m$;
2. there are no $y_i\ge0$ such that $\displaystyle\sum^m_{i=1}y_iP_i=-1$

This is an unusual phrasing Farkas' lemma.  My field is quite distant fro linear programming, so I love this phrasing because it mimics that of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

In the same blog TerenceTao assigns the following exercise.

**Exercise.**   Use Farkas’ lemma to derive the [duality theorem in linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Duality).

Can someone help me to understand how the two propositions are connected?

Comment: If you like "Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz" read Chapter 6 of Matoušek and Gärtner (2007), *Understanding and Using Linear Programming*, Springer. Around the proof, they go as far as mentioning "Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz" on p. 94.

Comment: This is THE book that I needed!